# MySQL distinct select for emoji always return 1 emoji out of 2

Tags: mysql

have these emojis stored in a reaction column. ,

If I run this query select a distinct reaction from chat_reactions where chat_id = 593 it only select the first one. My column's collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci but this issue doesn't happen for ❤️ (red love emoji)

How can I solve this?

Comment: to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve this by using a collation that treats the emojis as distinct.

Collation defines which characters are equal, less than, or greater than other characters.

Demo: I created a table like yours and filled it with the three emojis:

```
mysql> select reaction from chat_reactions;
+----------+
| reaction |
+----------+
|          |
|          |
| ❤️       |
+----------+
```

In utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation, those face emojis are considered the same, so they are collapsed into one row:

```
mysql> select distinct reaction collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci from chat_reactions;
+-------------------------------------+
| reaction collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                     |
| ❤️                                  |
+-------------------------------------+
```

But the more modern collations treat the face emojis as distinct:

```
mysql> select distinct reaction collate utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci from chat_reactions;
+-----------------------------------------+
| reaction collate utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                         |
|                                         |
| ❤️                                      |
+-----------------------------------------+

mysql> select distinct reaction collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci from chat_reactions;
+-------------------------------------+
| reaction collate utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------------------------------------+
|                                     |
|                                     |
| ❤️                                  |
+-------------------------------------+
```